# Cache Data for front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

I am using emberJS and nodeJS for my application development.
I have done completely differentiated front end and backend logic separately.
Now in my case i want to implement a cache logic for my front end application.
when ever i hits an api call to api/xxx, api/vehicve, api/users it will hit nodejs routes and fetch the data as response in front end.

I want to make all the server data in cache as front end and mean while , if server is down i can edit show case this data in my portal and can do edit and update on the cache data.

Is there any plugin or library to achieve caching in front and can edit and update?
Please guide an appropriate approach,

Comment: Did you try `ember-data`? Its a data persistence library maintained by the emberjs core team members.
https://github.com/emberjs/data

Comment: give this identity map I wrote a try - handles all the caching logic https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store